# Command from Resources ContextMenu does not trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, contextmenu

I need to use a context menu to restart services based on a datagrid (the context menu should send the name of the service as a CommandParameter)

The ContextMenu shows properly but clicking the MenuItems does not trigger the command (breakpoint not reached) but setting the context menu directly to a checkbox for example triggers the commands perfectly.

Ultimately, what I want is to get the context menu on right click on any item of the datagrid, clicking the menuitem should send either the Name column value or the whole selected item to the command in ViewModel (and then restart the process from there).

Really hurting my head for a few days, if you have any hints...

My Datagrid :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgServices" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="auto" HeadersVisibility="Row"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFC7E0EE" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFC7E0EE" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsServ}}">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                //GROUPSTYLE
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="373">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="356"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

ContainerStyle and ContextMenu in Window.Resources :

```
<Window.Resources>
<ContextMenu  x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="NULL" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="NAME" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="ITEM" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="ITEMS" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>
</ContextMenu>

 <Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
 </Style>

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsServ" Source="{Binding services, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Key" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The Checkbox used for testing :

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding autoStart, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Label Content="AutoStart"/>
                <CheckBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>
                        <!--<MenuItem Header="Edit" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgServices, Path=SelectedItem}" Command="{Binding restartService}"/>-->
                    </ContextMenu>
                </CheckBox.ContextMenu>
            </CheckBox>
```

ViewModel :

```
    private DelegateCommand _restartService;
    public DelegateCommand restartService
    {
        get
        {
            return _restartService ?? (_restartService = new DelegateCommand(o => TestCommand(o), o => true));
            //return _restartService ?? (_restartService = new DelegateCommand(o => MessageBox.Show($"{o.ToString()}\n{o.GetType()}"), o => true));
            //return _restartService ?? (_restartService = new DelegateCommand(o => Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", "/c net start "+o.ToString()) { Verb = "runas" }), o => true));
        }

    private void TestCommand(object o)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(o?.GetType()?.ToString() ?? "NULL");
    }
```

Comment: Is your command defined in the same ViewModel with `services` collection? Or in view model representing the separate item in `services` collection?

Comment: Try this:  `<MenuItem Header="NAME" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.restartService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>`

Comment: @mm8 this did not trigger the command either, and is it purposely missing the commandparameter?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes the Command is defined in the same view model as the collection services

Comment: @Phoque: What is `PlacementTarget.Type` ? Where is the `Type` property defined?

Comment: This was a missed typo from Copy/pasting lines, removed :p

Comment: @Phoque: So these are properties of the `DataGrid` control?

Comment: From what I understand these are supposed to return the datagrid properties indeed

Comment: My concern is that even when sending a x:Null it does not reach the command, so I guess there is a probleme with setting the datacontext to the context menu maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command property is defined in the view model of the `DataGrid`, you could bind the `Tag` property of the row to the `DataGrid`:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
</Style>
```

...and then try this:

```
<MenuItem Header="NAME"
          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.restartService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

Comment: YES! Actually this gives the name of the datagrid itself but changing to the SelectedItem I can Get the process name inside my Command.
Many thanks, Do you have some docs for the Tag I did not know about this

Comment: For future reference, I add a link here to explain what you did with the Tag property
https://www.spectrecoder.com/?p=51